# Fixed Side Menu using tailwind css

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

i am trying to create social media side bar on bottom right side.

right now it's working but when i scroll down it's not fixed.

i want it to remain fix on bottom right side regardless of screen size it should appear on bottom right side of screen.

how can i make it fixed.

**[CODE LINK](https://play.tailwindcss.com/zvvLImRhJP)**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" />

<div class="group relative z-50">
  <div class=" absolute  right-0 inset-y-96  w-10 group-hover:w-12   group-hover:mr-0 h-10 bg-yellow-500 flex items-center justify-center">
    <a href=""> <span class="mx-auto text-2xl  text-white cursor-pointer  fab fa-instagram "></span></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="group relative z-50">
  <div class=" absolute right-0 inset-y-96  mt-12 w-10 group-hover:w-12   group-hover:mr-0 h-10 bg-yellow-500 flex items-center justify-center">
    <a href="" target="_blank"> <span class="mx-auto text-2xl  text-white cursor-pointer  fab fa-facebook "></span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you've given position: relative instead of fixed.

```html
<div class="group fixed z-50 bottom-1/3 right-0">
<div class=" w-10 group-hover:w-12   group-hover:mr-0 h-10 bg-yellow-500 flex items-center justify-center">
<a href=""> <span class="mx-auto text-2xl  text-white cursor-pointer  fab fa-instagram "></span></a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="group fixed z-50 bottom-1/4 right-0">
<div class="w-10 group-hover:w-12   group-hover:mr-0 h-10 bg-yellow-500 flex items-center justify-center">
<a href="" target="_blank"> <span class="mx-auto text-2xl  text-white cursor-pointer  fab fa-facebook "></span></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposition. I Created extra `div` container with position `fixed` and `inset` properties additional negative `mt`. I hope you will be content ;-) Here You can see this in action [link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/OidT7dLDk3)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" />

<div class="fixed inset-3 inset-y-80 -mt-6">
  <div class="group relative z-50">
    <div class="absolute right-0 inset-y-96 w-10 group-hover:w-12 group-hover:mr-0 h-10 bg-yellow-500 flex items-center justify-center">
      <a href=""> <span class="mx-auto text-2xl text-white cursor-pointer fab fa-instagram"></span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group relative z-50">
    <div class="absolute right-0 inset-y-96 mt-12 w-10 group-hover:w-12 group-hover:mr-0 h-10 bg-yellow-500 flex items-center justify-center">
      <a href="" target="_blank"> <span class="mx-auto text-2xl text-white cursor-pointer fab fa-facebook"></span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou, but i opened your link but there's nothing to see in result.

Comment: @Fayakon check this out now.  Corrections done.

Comment: still blank it is